# Key Kollision in DES3 Implementation of PyCrypto

Tags: python, security, encryption, pycrypto

I'm pretty new to cryptography and only a user really. I stumbled however over a very interesting "vulnerability" of the DES3 Cipher of the PyCrypto library.

I experimented with generating Private Keys and encrypting them with DES3. Everything is fine with the following code:

```
from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA
from Crypto.Cipher import DES3
from Crypto import Random

random_generator = Random.new().read
key = RSA.generate(1024,random_generator)
public_key = key.publickey()
enc_data = public_key.encrypt('abcdefgh', 32)

exported_key = key.exportKey('PEM', '12345678abcdefgh', pkcs=1)
print(exported_key)
imported_key = RSA.importKey(exported_key,'12345678abcdefgi')

print(imported_key.exportKey('PEM'))
```

Note the minor change in the passphrase when importing the key. As expected, the result of the import is a fail, as the Private Key can not be decrypted correctly with the 16 byte passphrase provided. When I change the passphrase to the correct one, everything is fine.

However, when I experimented with encrypting something with DES3 (the standard encryption used in passphrase encrypting in this code), I stumbled accross something.

Regard the code:

```
from Crypto.Cipher import DES3

des = DES3.new("12345678abcdefgh")
secret = des.encrypt("1234abcd")
print(secret)

des2 = DES3.new("12345678abcdefgi")
result = des2.decrypt(secret)
print(result)
```

Which produces the following result:

```
��@e���
1234abcd
```

I can decode the message despite having an unauthorized key. For every other change I have tried so far ("12345678absdefgj" e.g.), encryption works as expected.

Is this a vulnerability in the DES3 cipher, an incorrect implementation or a fault in my "experiment"?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Technically speaking 3DES should not be used . Coming to your question , in this case what is happenning is this , 3des when used with 128 bit key actually uses 112 bits . Even reading the documentation of pycrypto it says this Parameters:
key (byte string) - The secret key to use in the symmetric cipher. It must be 16 or 24 bytes long. The parity bits will be ignored. So the small change is not changing the 112 bits and hence you are able to decrypt the data .

Comment: Thank you, this is kind of what I expected. Is there a way to go for storing private keys in a database/on harddisk without external security hardware in pycrypto?